# is there any way to tell v8 to preserve p-code for the next 'page' that loads the same javascript library

Tags: javascript, v8

Scenario: In order to make lighthouse analytics happy (ie reduce download, blocking, etc. etc. etc.) a web app has been chopped up so that previously in-page dialogues/sequences
are now independent, subsequently loaded pages.

Naturally this means that a single library link download has now become a download for each of the resulting dialog pages.  As far as download *size*, any caching mechanism will   ameliorate any multiplier.  Although v8/closure has been used to massively shrink the download size - this leaves the blocking problem of reparsing and recompiling for every instance (when only one parse/compile on the target/client *should* actually be needed, if we were optimal).

So, the question is, is there any mechanism to flag library code such that the v8 engine
retains and reuses the p-code it parsed the first time??  [Note, a ServiceWorker implementation is *not* the answer for the library/framework.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

V8, in combination with the way it's embedded into Chrome, does have the ability to cache code. You don't need to flag anything; just like HTTP caching, the browser has certain heuristics to decide by itself whether/when to cache things.

Comment: Thank you.  I was hoping for something like that but did not find any references in the documentation.  Code caching makes it much easier to  'progressively' build an app - load some of the foundation at the front door, a little more here and a little more there, building on what has been loaded as the user progresses through any sequences.